# Android WebView Disable <Audio> Tag

Tags: android, html, audio, webview

My Android WebView is loading a 3rd party URL.

I.e.http://www.desiringgod.org/resource-library/sermons/gods-good-news-concerning-his-son

It works great, however because of the  tag which gets loaded through javascript, the WebView begins downloading the mp3 without user input as soon as the page loads.

I have tried calling WebView.stopLoading() once progress has finished, as well as shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) to try to catch ending with ".mp3" but it doesn't seem to be able to able to stop it!

My main concern is the amount of data it automatically downloads, if there's any way to stop the download or replace the  tags before the page loads that would be great.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** actually I found the reason the Audio tags were loading without user prompt is because it is using flash. Once I enabled plugins on webview it stops downloading by itself. However I will still be interested to know how to stop  tags within webviews in Android downloading data in background without user knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know WebView itself, but if the `audio` tag is being used, you can ask the browser to not download the audio file by setting the `preload` attribute to `none`.

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to find the preload attribute in webview: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: As I said, I know nothing about WebView as I've never used it I'm simply referring to HTML5's audio tag and it's preload attribute.